# Checkstyle in Jenkins - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: maven, jenkins, checkstyle

I am trying to get checkstyle to work in jenkins. In maven alone, everything runs smoothly, but when I run the checkstyle:checkstyle target in jenkins, the follwong error apperas:

```
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10(default-cli)
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lhudson/plugins/analysis/core/AnnotationParser;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at hudson.plugins.checkstyle.CheckStyleReporter.perform(CheckStyleReporter.java:123)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwareReporter.postExecute(HealthAwareReporter.java:313)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:421)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(Maven3Builder.java:403)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:87)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:228)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
... 18 more
channel stopped
```

I am using the following versions:

- Jenkins ver. 1.480.3
- Checkstyle Plugin 3.35
- Static Analysis Collector Plug-in 1.35
- Maven Integration plugin 1.480.3